# how to query adobe data feeds to get time spent on page

Tags: sql, adobe, adobe-analytics

I have ingested adobe analytics data(data feeds) to hadoop.
now I want to calculate average time spent on a page by querying this dataset.
can anybody help me out

This is what i have made which is incomplete

```
SELECT count(distinct concat(hitid_high,hitid_low)) ,sub(pst_cust_hit_time_gmt-pst_cust_hit_time_gmt) as time_spent FROM <table> 
WHERE exclude_hit LIKE "0" AND hit_source NOT IN ('5','7','8','9') and pg_event like "0"
GROUP BY count(distinct concat(pst_visid_high, pst_visid_low, visit_num))
ORDER BY visit_page_num ASC;
```

This is what i have found in adobe website.

**Time Spent:**

To calculate time spent, you must group hits by visit, then order them according to the hit number within the visit.

1.Exclude all rows where exclude_hit > 0

2.Group hits for a visit by concatenating visid_high , visid_low , and visit_num

3.Order hits for each visit by visit_page_num

4.Using page_event , filter the types of hits you want

5.Find hits where the value you want to track time spent is set. For example: hit 1: post_prop1=red hit 2: pos
t_prop1=blue

6.Subtract the post_cust_hit_time for hit 1 from the post_cust_hit_time for hit 2 to determine the seconds between these two hits. The result is the time spent for post_prop1=red . If this results in a negative number, it indicates that the hit was received out-of-order and the calculation should be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on something similar in order to calculate the time required for a customer to go between funnel steps. It is not exactly the answer to your question but might give you some additional information of how in general to calculate the time difference between various steps.

https://analyticsmayhem.com/adobe-analytics/adobe-analytics-funnel-steps-measure-time/

Let me know if you would like to discuss more.

Cheers, Konstantinos

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation tells us how to calculate the difference between the timestamp of entry on the first visited page vs the timestamp of entry on last visited page, but not how much time we spent on the last page. Therefore, it will always be less than what you see in the adobe_analytics reports.

This also means you can't calculate the `time_spent` for **bounce visits** since the first visited page is the last visited page.

This is just what I surmised from trying to analyze data through Data Feed, but I could be wrong.